# OpenGL, SSBO std430 padding byte size

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader, shader-storage-buffer

This is the fragment shader code which is including struct and buffer data:

```
struct Light
{
    float range;
    vec3 position;  
    vec3 color;
};

layout (std430) buffer LocalLights
{
    uint activeLightCount;
    Light light[];
} localLights;
```

If I assume that the light[] is total 10, what is total size of LocalLights data and the Light struct size data?

I want to use these function:

```
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, size, data, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, offset1, activeLightCountSize, data_of_count);
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, offset2, totalLightStructSize, data_of_array);
```

For example:
If I have the array which is std::vector data_of_array and assumes this vector has 10 element.
In this case, what is size of activeCountSize, offset2, totalLightStructSize?

Try to get size of data.
Get total size of LocalLights data and the Light struct size data?

Comment: My guess is `activeLightCountSize`: 4bytes (an int), `totalLightStructSize` = 10 * 3 * 4 * sizeof(float) = 48 bytes. All members of the struct should be padded to vec4. `offset2`: probably 16, because all members of the LocalLights struct are padded to vec4, but not sure about this one. I definitely would advice not to define the struct like this, it causes an massive amount of padding and makes the outcome hard to predict. I would just put 7 floats in there (or at least 2 vec4 where positions.w contains range).

Comment: I changed the struct like that:
vec4 position; -> position.w is range
vec4 color;
after doing like that I follow your way, and it works correctly.

I really feel that it is more comfortable set vec4 for making easy padding size :(

Thank you!